# SharePoint Designer Workflow extract part of URL

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, string

Reusable workflow (content type  based) running on a Document set. I need to extract the name of the Parent Document set while a workflow is running on the documents inside a doc set.

I get the full url using [Workflow context : Current Item URL] as below

```
http://somesite/sites/TestWF/ResumeBank/Tina Garcia/Cover Letter.docx
```

Tina Garcia is what i want to extract from the above.
How do I extract using the extract string actions in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Copy from [Workflow context : Current Item URL], starting at 46 gives me:

```
Tina Garcia/Cover Letter.docx
```

Now I need to extract just Tina Garcia. I can get the name of the file using [Current Item : Name] which gives me `Cover Letter.docx`
Any help would me appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look into [SharePoint Designer Workflow String Actions](https://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/) or [SharePoint Designer Workflow Extensions](https://spdwfextensions.codeplex.com/) or [String Workflow Actions for SharePoint 2013/Online](https://spworkflowactions.codeplex.com/).

You can just install these solutions in order to access the functionality they offer, including string manipulation that you need.